# How do I create a class in a html block for the view I am on in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this code that is my navigation bar on my site, it is in my _layout.cshtml page at the top...

```
<div  id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="current"><a href="/home/index">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/code/index">Code Stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="/music/index">Music Stuff</a></li>
                <li><a href="/blog/index">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/links/index">Links</a></li>   
                <li><a href="/contact/index">Contact</a></li>   
            </ul>       
        </div>
```

Im using a razor view page and I need to be able to inject **id="current"** into the block for the page that im on. My solution was to do something like

```
<div  id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li id="@Model.PageName"><a href="/home/index">Home</a></li>
                <li id="@Model.PageName"><a href="/code/index">Code Stuff</a></li>
                <li id="@Model.PageName"><a href="/music/index">Music Stuff</a></li>
                <li id="@Model.PageName"><a href="/blog/index">Blog</a></li>
                <li id="@Model.PageName"><a href="/links/index">Links</a></li>  
                <li id="@Model.PageName"><a href="/contact/index">Contact</a></li>  
            </ul>       
        </div>
```

But of course that wont work because all of the li items will have the pagename in. So without using burly if statements how can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you really should be using class (as indicated in your title) rather than id (as indicated in your question text).  Second, I would define a function that takes an argument differentiated your link and outputs either the empty string or `current` depending on whether it matches the page name.

```
 @functions
 {
     public string MenuClass( string menuItem )
     {
         return string.Equals( Model.PageName, menuItem, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
                     ? "current"
                     : "";
     }
 }


 <div  id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="@MenuClass("Home")"><a href="/home/index">Home</a></li>
            <li class="@MenuClass("Code")"><a href="/code/index">Code Stuff</a></li>
            ...  
        </ul>       
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi, where do I put the function in the controller? Don't suppose you could give me a hint at what you suggest for the mark up could you?

Comment: @Pete2k the function goes in the view, I've added an example.

Comment: Hey thanks....Ok I see what your doing, I put this on the _layout page but the Model is null , is that normal?

Comment: I got I got it okay i beginning to understand, ive created a model and then put the pagename into it before returning it in my call to View() on the controller! Thanks :-)